# How to find out user is online or not in Quickblox?

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I am using Quickblox javascript SDK for video chat.

Is there any way to get online status of the user?

As per documentation user "last_requested_at" field only updated when user login to the app, so how to figure out user is online or not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's available since 1.13.0

http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript#Download_JavaScript_SDK

```
var dialogJid = "...";

QB.chat.muc.listOnlineUsers(dialogJid, function(users) {

});
```

http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Get_online_users

Comment: ok thanks, but i am using webRTC https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-web